# Can I use MobiForms for my game development?

Tags: iphone

Just now I found [MobiForms](http://www.mobiforms.com/). I am planning to create a game for the iPhone using it.

My problem is I know only Objective-C and I have designed only one app (which is also a game) that's currently in the AppStore.

Can I use MobiForms for game development?

Comment: PLEASE! Format your text so it is human-readable!

Answer (score 3):

MobiForms looks like it's designed for businesses to rapidly create domain specific business applications that basically look... like forms. It doesn't look like it's well-suited to making interesting games.

So while I'm sure you could leverage MobiForms to create some kind of program that would resemble a game, since it's not really designed for it I would say that you shouldn't use it -- especially since it costs money. You'd be better off putting that money elsewhere, like towards a [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) license, perhaps.

Comment: thanks josh..is there any usage with the mobiform other than form creation..means will it use full for pdf readers or ebub generation or any education related apps..

Comment: I guess you could use it for that sort of thing. You'd have to examine the API and feature set and see.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a number of games you could make with it!

- Press the button
- Press the button X times in Y seconds
- Press the button faster than anyone else
- Press the button timed to the background music
- Don't press the button
- Press the button... IF YOU DARE

These are sure winners, especially in the iPhone market!

More seriously though, I can imagine Minesweeper, Tic-Tac-Toe, and the Guess the Number game are examples of games which could indeed be made with this library, along with most (if not all) puzzle games and many casual games.

Games can exist on just about any medium in some form. Maybe not the games you're thinking of, but then you should perhaps look up the definitions of "game".

Comment: Sounds like the sort of games you'd find at http://www.excelgames.org/